# Can I intercept command line arguments to pytest?

Tags: python, command-line, pytest

I am pretty fond of **pytest** and especially its ability to just run **unittest** tests just fine.  However, I have some hacks around unittest that I don't know how to reproduce with pytest, so I can't write full pytest-only tests yet.

Best shown, rather than explained.

```
import unittest

import sys

def active():
    print("active")

def f_default():
    print("inactive")


class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_it(self):
        print("passed")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    flag = "--systrace"

    if flag in sys.argv:
        f_default = active
        sys.argv.remove(flag)

    f_default()
    unittest.main()
```

Basically, if pass in `--systrace` on the command line, I intercept it, flip some state in the test script, that is not necessarily given to the unittests, and then remove it from `sys.argv`. unittest is none the wiser.

#### with the switch:

```
python test_unittest_commandline.py --systrace
active
passed
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

#### without the switch:

```
$ python test_unittest_commandline.py
inactive
passed
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s
```

#### pytest is not impressed

This is to be expected, since I am not on `__main__` so I never strip out the unexpected argument.  Is there a pytest hook that I can use to scrub out sys.argv and note the value of the argument?  Again, I don't care to parametrize the tests or pytest itself.  I never had much luck with **nose** as a test runner doing this, but nose does not bring its own enhancements to unittests either.

```
pytest test_unittest_commandline.py --systrace
ERROR: usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: --systrace
  inifile: None
  rootdir: /explore
```

Comment: You can add project-specific command line args via the `pytest_addoption` hook and you can remove stuff from `sys.argv` before starting the test execution, e.g. in the `pytest_sessionstart` hook.

Comment: @hoefling Txs, those 2 look like just what I needed!  I'll check them out later and let you know.